# How to use Firebase Query for data with anonymous keys

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have the following database data which I intend to display on a ListView with FirebaseListAdapter 
[image]

My problem is creating a Query since the child elements after date are anonymous. Here is the query code

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Updates").child(refMail).child(day)
            .orderByKey();
```

refMail and day are user email address and date respectively.

Here is also my Data Model Class

```
public class NotesDataModel {

private String Note;
private String uid;
private String time;

public NotesDataModel(){

}

public NotesDataModel(String Note, String uid, String time){
    this.Note=Note;
    this.uid=uid;
    this.time=time;
}

public String getNote() {
    return Note;
}

public void setNote(String note) {
    Note = note;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}}
```

and finally the adapter initialization

```
 FirebaseListOptions<NotesDataModel> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<NotesDataModel>()
            .setQuery(query, NotesDataModel.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.notes_cell_layout)
            .build();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<NotesDataModel>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, NotesDataModel note, int position) { //some code }}; notesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Previous version worked like this

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(FactoryDaftari.firebaseURL + "Updates/" + refMail + "/" + day);
```

And the Adapter initialization

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<NotesDataModel>(this, NotesDataModel.class, R.layout.notes_cell_layout, ref) {

        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, NotesDataModel note, int position) { }};
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to make this query with the way your data is structured.  It's common in NoSQL databases to make copies of data, structured for the purpose of specialized querying.  So, if you want to query a list of notes, you'll need a structure where all the notes are children of the same parent, then make your query against that structure.

(Also, organizing your notes by a node with a date, like you have now, may not even be the best general structure in the first place.)

Comment: It used to work with the previous version of Firebase UI that didn't require Query and FirebaseListOptions. The problem started after I updated and changed the code structure to what I've posted

Comment: Then you might want to make that clear in your question.